# How to get exact capacity from storage

Tags: android, size, storage, capacity, android-internal-storage

I want to read the exact capacity from the intern storage programmatically.

I's a Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge 32GB device what I am using.

In the preinstalled Samsung FileManager (In German: Eigene Dateien) it shows me the total capacity of 32GB. 
Even in the menu => settings => Storage it shows me 32GB.

(Showed in screenshots)

When I use my code below it shows me a total capacity of 24,4GB.

(Showed in Log at the end of the post)

***Question: How to get the exact 32GB total capacity of my device?***

**Screenshots**

[image: File Manager (Samsung)] [image: Storage (Settings)]

**Full Code:**

```
package spicysoftware.com.space;

import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.StatFs;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    StatFs stat = new StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String InternalFreeSpace = convertBytes(getInternalFreeSpace());
        Log.v("InternalFreeSpace : ", InternalFreeSpace);

        String InternalTotalSpace = convertBytes(getInternalTotalSpace());
        Log.v("InternalTotalSpace : ", InternalTotalSpace);

        String InternalUsedSpace = convertBytes(getInternalUsedSpace());
        Log.v("InternalUsedSpace : ", InternalUsedSpace);

    }

    public long getInternalFreeSpace()    {
        //Get free Bytes...
        long bytesAvailable = stat.getBlockSizeLong() * stat.getAvailableBlocksLong();
        return bytesAvailable;
    }

    public long getInternalTotalSpace()    {
        //Get total Bytes
        long bytesTotal = (stat.getBlockSizeLong() * stat.getBlockCountLong());
        return bytesTotal;
    }

    public long getInternalUsedSpace()    {
        //Get used Bytes
        long bytesUsed = getInternalTotalSpace() - getInternalFreeSpace();
        return bytesUsed;
    }

    public static String convertBytes (long size){
        long Kb = 1  * 1024;
        long Mb = Kb * 1024;
        long Gb = Mb * 1024;
        long Tb = Gb * 1024;
        long Pb = Tb * 1024;
        long Eb = Pb * 1024;

        if (size <  Kb)                 return floatForm(        size     ) + " byte";
        if (size >= Kb && size < Mb)    return floatForm((double)size / Kb) + " KB";
        if (size >= Mb && size < Gb)    return floatForm((double)size / Mb) + " MB";
        if (size >= Gb && size < Tb)    return floatForm((double)size / Gb) + " GB";
        if (size >= Tb && size < Pb)    return floatForm((double)size / Tb) + " TB";
        if (size >= Pb && size < Eb)    return floatForm((double)size / Pb) + " PB";
        if (size >= Eb)                 return floatForm((double)size / Eb) + " EB";

        return "anything...";
    }

    public static String floatForm (double d)    {
        return new DecimalFormat("#.##").format(d);
    }
}
```

**Log**

[image: Log]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I use my code below it shows me a total capacity of 24,4GB.

That is the amount of space on the partition that contains `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`. There will be other partitions on the device, for which you will not have access.

> How to get the exact 32GB total capacity of my device?

There is no means of doing that, except perhaps on a rooted device.

Comment: I have a non rooted device. And there mus be a way... Because other apps can read the 32GB capacity of my device..

Comment: @MSeiz5: I cannot see a reliable way of doing that via `StatFs`. Perhaps there is some other approach. It would not surprise me if other apps are doing unreliable things like run the `df` command and parse the output.

Comment: Okay. Summarized that means the 24,4GB is the correct output and 7,6GB is reserved in other paritions (for example os or system data?) But I think you are right. It doesn't make sense for the user that 32GB is showed although only 24,4GB are usable. Thanks! :)

Comment: @MSeiz5: "7,6GB is reserved in other paritions (for example os or system data?)" -- yes, that will be things like the recovery/upgrade partition and stuff. The details are likely to vary significantly by device and OS version.

Answer (score 5):

1.First ,open command prompt. Connect your mobile where developer option is on. Write `"adb shell"` on cmd.You will be now in your phone path.
2.Secondly, write `df -h` on cmd, which show you the total phone storage is divided into different disk path.

3.See this image.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzgmk.png)

```
  `  double size =
                    new File("/data").getTotalSpace() / (1024.0 * 1024 * 1024);


            double sizesystem =
                    new File("/system").getTotalSpace() / (1024.0 * 1024 * 1024);

            double sizedev =
                    new File("/dev").getTotalSpace() / (1024.0 * 1024 * 1024);

            double sizecache =
                    new File("/cache").getTotalSpace() / (1024.0 * 1024 * 1024);

            double sizemnt =
                    new File("/mnt").getTotalSpace() / (1024.0 * 1024 * 1024);

            double sizevendor =
                    new File("/vendor").getTotalSpace() / (1024.0 * 1024 * 1024);



            float total = (float) (sizemnt + sizedev + sizesystem + size + sizevendor + sizecache);
            Log.e("total111", String.valueOf(total));`
```

Here, usE the all dish path and get the size.Then sum up all and get the actual storage of a phone.
iF phone is 32 GB, you will see the  32 GB total storage.