# Get Android device storage capacity

Tags: android

I'd like to get the device storage capacity as displayed in Settings -> Storage - usually something like: 32 / 64 / 128 / 256 GB.

I used this post (and a few similar ones): 
[It is possible to get total storage capacity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14531806/it-is-possible-to-get-total-storage-capacity)

I've got this code:

```
    StatFs stat = new StatFs(Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
    long gb = 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
    long size = stat.getTotalBytes() / gb;
```

This returns 47GB on a 64GB Samsung S8 and 111GB on a 128GB Huawei Mate 10 - not what I was looking for.

How to get the 64GB / 128GB values?
Thanks!!

**Update**

This is the same as this question: [How to get exact capacity from storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43004556/how-to-get-exact-capacity-from-storage).
Unfortunately the accepted answer states that it's not possible to get the storage info - I was hoping to get a different answer .. maybe not using **StatFs** but some other way.

Comment: The total space is typically split into partitions (see for example https://forum.xda-developers.com/general/general/android-partitions-explained-t3657183). So not all is available in the file system.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get exact capacity from storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43004556/how-to-get-exact-capacity-from-storage)

Comment: Thanks Henry - is it maybe possible not with StatFs but some other way?

Comment: @Daniel did you check the answer by CommonsWare (he is **the Android Guru**) of duplicate question I mentioned above. It clearly states that it is not possible to get phone's storage capacity by any API (maybe possible for rooted devices). Check it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43005006/631803

Comment: @VicJordan yes .. I saw, thanks .. I'll try for a few more days before giving in

Comment: Did you get the answer.Kindly forward that to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62797927/not-getting-correct-value-of-storage-volumeinternal

Answer (score 4):

You can try to use something like this (added in API level 26):

1. use `StorageManager#getStorageVolumes()` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/storage/StorageManager#getStorageVolumes() to get all storage volumes UUID's
2. via `StorageStatsManager#getTotalBytes(java.util.UUID)` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/StorageStatsManager#getTotalBytes(java.util.UUID) you can find total bytes for each storage
3. sum up sizes for all storages you need.

Comment: Thanks Igor - I tried this way - I get null from storageVolume.getUuid() .. also this would only work on very new devices (Android 8+)

Comment: @Daniel When it's null, it means it's the primary one, so you need to use `StorageManager.UUID_DEFAULT` instead. Also, I think that the sum of what you get is only the storage that's ever can be available to the user (meaning without the system stuff).

Answer (score -1):

You can use below snippet for getting the total internal memory.

```
File path=Environment.getDataDirectory();
StatFs stat=new StatFs(path.getPath());
long blockSize=stat.getBlockSize();
long availableBlocks=stat.getBlockCount();
long totalInternalMemory=availableBlocks*blockSize;
```

Comment: Thanks Joy, this returns the same as stat.getTotalBytes() in my code .. but it's not the total storage unfortunately

Comment: it's not capacity!