# Not getting correct value of Storage Volume(Internal)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, storage, android-storage

I want total internal space available in Phone but in this code `getInternalFreeSpace` returns correct value but `getInternalStorageSpace` doesn't return exact available space because of not counting ANDROID OS Size.

Like my phone has 64GB but this code returns 51.6GB.

**The Only missing is 12.40 GB i.e. ANDROID OS size, 51.6GB + 12.40 = 64.00**

```
fun getInternalStorageSpace(): Float{
    val statsFs = StatFs(Environment.getDataDirectory().absolutePath)
    val sizeKB = statsFs.blockCountLong.toFloat() * statsFs.blockSizeLong
    val sizeMB = sizeKB/ (1024 * 1024)
    val sizeGB = sizeMB/1024
    return sizeGB
}

fun getInternalFreeSpace(): Float{
    val statsFs = StatFs(Environment.getDataDirectory().absolutePath)
    val sizeKB = statsFs.availableBlocksLong.toFloat() * statsFs.blockSizeLong
    val sizeMB = sizeKB/ (1024*1024)
    val sizeGB = sizeMB / 1024
    return sizeGB
}

fun getInternalUsedSpace(): Float{
    val statsFs = StatFs(Environment.getDataDirectory().absolutePath)
    val total = statsFs.blockCountLong.toFloat() * statsFs.blockSizeLong / (1024 * 1024)
    val free = statsFs.availableBlocksLong.toFloat() * statsFs.blockSizeLong / (1024 * 1024)
    return total - free
}
```

Comment: Available = space - inuse.

Comment: Use 1000 instead of 1024.

Comment: not worked for me

Comment: Well how much was it then?

Comment: Issue is with Android Os memory... 1024 is correct

Comment: Ask the hard disk manufacturers.

Answer (score 0):

try this code, the bytesToMegaBytes method is simple converter. I'm using StorageManager API. You need check each volume

```
 public static int freeStorage(Context context){
    StorageStatsManager storageStatsManager = (StorageStatsManager) context.getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
    StorageManager storageManager = (StorageManager) context.getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE);
    try {
        if(storageManager!=null && storageStatsManager!=null) {
            List<StorageVolume> storageVolumes = storageManager.getStorageVolumes();
            for (StorageVolume storageVolume : storageVolumes) {
                final String uuidStr = storageVolume.getUuid();
                final UUID uuid = uuidStr == null ? StorageManager.UUID_DEFAULT : UUID.fromString(uuidStr);
                return  bytesToMegaBytes(storageStatsManager.getFreeBytes(uuid));
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }catch (Exception e){
        Timber.d(e);
        return 0;
    }
}
```